# Is there a way to use MongoDB query objects to filter regular JavaScript arrays?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In MongoDB, you can use JSON-style objects such as in the following to query a collection:

```
db.things.find({ x : { $ne : 3 }, y : 'foo' });
```

I'd like to reuse that `{ x : { $ne : 3 }, y : 'foo' }` bit and use it to filter an array of JavaScript objects.

Is there any code/library out there that can do that, and that supports all the query options (or as much as makes sense anyway)?

Comment: sounds like a good suggestion for the MongoDB folks to add to their library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, so here's another try:

> [sift.js](https://github.com/crcn/sift.js) (npm: sift) by Craig Condon is a MongoDB-inspired array
> filtering library. It’s a bit like an alternative to Underscore for
> people who love MongoDB. Sift.js supports operators like $in and $gt,
> but can also filter arrays based on functions and even works with
> deeply-nested objects in arrays.
>
> Craig has provided a few examples that should look familiar to Mongo
> users:

```
var sift = require('sift');

sift({ $in: ['hello','world'] }, ['hello','sifted','array!']); //
['hello']
```

Source (Edited): Daily JS, but seems site is down.

Comment: Oh, this looks perfect! Nice find. Thanks

Comment: @Emil, thats a nice find.. +1

Comment: Wow! The best one ever used for far.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see, [Mingo](https://github.com/kofrasa/mingo) has wider Mongo queries support than Sift.

Answer (score 2):

[Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) is a great library to do map/reduce kind of jobs on javascript structures. Highly recommended.

Comment: Those are also natively available in `Array.prototype` on more modern browsers. I think the OP is wanting to pass an object to filter the Mongo way (I guess including atomic operations like `$in`).

Comment: Correct, I want to be able to use the same filter to filter MongoDB data _and_ regular JavaScript arrays

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/mirek/node-json-criteria library, which evaluates critera queries in MongoDB format on JSON objects.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think you can just use the mongodb filters in normal js arrays. Because you need to understand the fact that

> The filters specified in mongodb are evaluated in
>   mongodb indexes not in the javascript result set

Means the filters evaluated(translated) to query against a index not the js. So what you are asking is a DSL on top of mongodb(or JS) which will evaluate the mongodb index filters in the JS array.

I dont think its needed since both serves the different purposes (Though its possible(difficult) to write custom DSL). Also there are major frameworks like underscore.js already provide a ways to handle these.