# What Javascript library can evaluate MongoDB-like query predicates against an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, predicate

Is there a javascript library that will allow me to express object predicates in a DSL similar to MongoDB's query language? For the sake of clarity in a large program, I'd like to be able to say:

```
var obj = { 
    a: 1, 
    b: 'abcdefg' 
}, qry = { 
    a: { $gt: 0 }, 
    b: /^abc/ 
}; 

if(query(qry).matches(obj)) { 
    // do something appropriate since 
}
```

instead of:

```
var obj = { 
    a: 1, 
    b: 'abcdefg' 
}; 
if(obj.a>0 && qry.b.test(obj.b)) { 
    // do something appropriate 
}
```

I'm using Node.js, so anything on [NPM](https://npmjs.org/) would be great. It would be an added bonus if the library can select objects out of an array as well as just matching individual objects.

I reviewed these two related questions, but they weren't particularly helpful for my situation:

- [Implementing goMongoDB-like Query expression object evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972025/implementing-mongodb-like-query-expression-object-evaluation)
- [Evaluating MongoDB-like JSON Queries in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070460/evaluating-mongodb-like-json-queries-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use MongoDB query objects to filter regular JavaScript arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695718/is-there-a-way-to-use-mongodb-query-objects-to-filter-regular-javascript-arrays)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OK I found the answer: [Sift.js](https://github.com/crcn/sift.js)

Now for the long answer: This has been [asked and answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695718/is-there-a-way-to-use-mongodb-query-objects-to-filter-regular-javascript-arrays). The salient points are:

- Use Sift if you really want Mongo syntax
- If you want to be more mainstream, use [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) like everyone else. It has heaps of handy functions in addition to the fact that it basically does what sift does with a slightly different syntax.
- You may not need any library at all - modern browsers support many useful functions directly on the [Array prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype), like `filter()` for example.

As a final note, [mongodb-riff](https://github.com/jostylr/mongodb-riff) appears to be trying to do something similar but currently the page states clearly that it doesn't work - perhaps it's abandoned. But his readme is at least of value :-), he mentions sift and [Query Engine](https://github.com/bevry/query-engine) which looks more mature, though too complicated for me!

Personally I'm going to go with Underscore because now that I've looked into it for the first time, I realise that it has heaps of handy stuff I need, plus I really only wanted to do simple functions like what would be `_.find()` in Underscore. But I guess if you want to do more complicated mongo-like queries, you'll do it in less LOC with Sift.

Comment: well, i figured there'd be something - and why not on Github? i probably should have looked for myself, but i was hoping someone else had come across it already. let's see if you can steal the prize from @Vivin ^_^!

Comment: awesome! [Sift.js](https://github.com/crcn/sift.js) looks just right. i do like and use [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)/[Lodash](http://lodash.com/), but need to re-use predicates already stored inside Mongo. thank you!

Comment: oh, and thank you for finding [the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695718]. i searched but didn't find it ^_^;

Comment: There's also balupton's [query-engine](https://github.com/bevry) which is feature rich and mature.

Answer (score 9):

Check out [Mingo](https://github.com/kofrasa/mingo)

I implemented it after finding no suitable alternative.

It is still actively being developed but is usable. Test coverage is not complete.

Usable from both browser and nodejs

[Edit]

This library is now the most complete implementation of MongoDB's query language for the frontend.

Comment: Both sift and Mingo are great, but [MSON](https://github.com/redgeoff/mson) is switching to Mingo as Mingo has support for aggregations.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/mirek/node-json-criteria library does exactly that - evaluates criteria queries on JSON objects using MongoDB query format.

Answer (score 1):

## lodash.js

You want to use lodash.js. Its a drop in replacement for underscore.js.
The performance is twice as fast.

http://lodash.com/

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could find was [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/), which is LINQ for JavaScript. Hopefully this will be of some help to you.

Comment: i don't think it's what i'm looking for - but that's definitely not your fault! maybe no one has made anything like that yet. i'll consider [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) and see if it helps at all. thank you, @Vivin!