# How to match mongo document against an array of rules one by one

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rule-engine

I do a find and get a single document back. I also have a set of mongo rules. I need to match the document against this set of rules and if the document matches a rule, append the name of the rule to a rule-name subdocument.

Assume the document is this -

```
var randomGuy = { name: "Random Guy", age: 45, state: "assam", profession: "coder", ruleNames: [] };
```

I have that stored in a JavaScript variable. I also have a set of rules, converted to mongodb rules -

```
var rules = [
       {'rule1': { name: /R*/i, age: { $gt: 40 } }},
       {'rule2': { state: "karnataka" }},
       {'rule3': { age: { $lt: 60 } }},
       {'rule4': { $or: [ { profession: 'coder' }, { profession: 'programmer' } ] }}
    ];
```

I want to loop over the rules, match the randomGuy object against each and append the rule names to the randomGuy's ruleNames property. So the final randomGuy object looks like this -

```
var randomGuy = { name: "Random Guy", age: 45, state: "assam", profession: "coder", ruleNames: ['rule1', 'rule3', 'rule4'] };
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to implement a rule engine that understands the rule format you're using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what Javascript library can evaluate MongoDB-like query predicates against an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397668/what-javascript-library-can-evaluate-mongodb-like-query-predicates-against-an-ob)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i found the answer in sift.js - https://github.com/crcn/sift.js

All i will need to do is apply the rules as sift filters on the randomGuy object.

```
var randomGuys = [randomGuy];
var ruleName, ruleString;
rules.forEach(function(rule) {
    ruleName = Object.keys(rule)[0];
    ruleString = rule[ruleName];
    if(sift(ruleString).test(randomGuy)) {
        randomGuys.ruleNames.push(ruleName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice lib, didn't know it existed :)

Comment: Got it from this SO answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397668/what-javascript-library-can-evaluate-mongodb-like-query-predicates-against-an-ob

That guy asked the right question ;)